# Do badges give you reputation points?

Tags: discussion, reputation, badges

On stackoverflow I see many different ways to get badges. Besides collecting just a list of badges for various tasks, do any badges award reputation points when you get them? I ask because I know certain things only become available when you have certain reputation point levels.

Comment: Not directly, but some badges indicate that you got lots of upvotes for your post.

Comment: Badges don't give rep but a very small number of actions are allowed only for people with specfic badges

Comment: @KateGregory What actions are unlockable by badge only? Never heard of that.

Comment: @WesleyMurch funny you should ask: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168661/147247

Comment: @KateGregory Ah, so I can be a Moderator if I get those badges? ;) "Reviewer" is just another badge, not an unlockable action.

Comment: @WesleyMurch well you can't if you don't :-)

Comment: "Hi Wesley, we think you're a perfect candidate for Moderator, all your paperwork checks out, we don't have any other applicants, *buuuuuutt* we noticed you don't have **Strunk and White**. Thanks, sorry, good luck." ;)

Comment: @WesleyMurch Reminded me of "Dear Peter Wiggin: This letter is to inform you that you have received enough upvotes on your reddit comments to become president of the world.  Please be at the UN tomorrow at 8:00 sharp." http://xkcd.com/635/  :)

Comment: There's a chance that a person saw you had a gold badge and immediately upvoted you without reading the body.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No, none of the badges award any reputation.  You'll gain reputation for many of the actions required to get badges, but no extra reputation is awarded for a badge itself.

Comment: Announcer badge is typically one of those badges where I feel you evidently provided a valuable improvement to the quality of the site that it should honor you with a few points.

Comment: I would argue the Archeologist and Archivist as well.