# Should the Badges page include the (very few) details on privs unlocked by a badge?

Tags: discussion, badges, badge-description

You [must have](https://stackoverflow.com/election/3) Convention, Strunk and White, Civic Duty, and Deputy to stand for election as a moderator. (I'm not actually sure whether that's SE-wide, or just SO.) And at one point you [had to have Strunk and White](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129317/147247) to qualify for Reviewer. I don't know if that's still the case or not because I have it.

For these four, and perhaps for others if they exist, can we add to the badge descriptions page?

> 10 posts with score of 2 on meta. You must hold this badge to be nominated as a moderator
>
> Edited 80 posts.  You must hold this badge to be nominated as a moderator

... etc ...

> Completed at least 250 review tasks. This badge is awarded once per review type and only to those with the Strunk and White badge

Something like that...

Comment: The election requirements are not SE-wide.  I'm an elected mod on Mi Yodeya and didn't have all those.

Comment: Except convention, I have em all on Chemistry SE.

Answer (score 2):

The badges necessary for an election are dependent on the site, and on the election (they change, as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8041931/revisions)). In fact, the current badge requirements you see are *last election's badges*, since the election wiki hasn't been updated yet.

The Strunk and White requirement is no longer there for Reviewer, so there *aren't* any "badge unlocks" left.

Comment: Are the badge descriptions the same across sites, or are they allowed to diverge?

Comment: @KateGregory: Not sure. The privilege pages are the same across sites (and they are editable by MSO 10ks). As a mod, I can't edit the badge pages on my sites (dunno about MSO mods), but I guess a dev can do it. Not sure.

Comment: @KateGregory: Also, how will that help if the requirements change every time? The 2011 election [required 6 badges](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8041931/1). Last election, it was 4. This election, it may change. When should the "unlock" info be edited into the badge page, and when should it be changed? AFAICT the requirements are decided at election time, so this change to the badge page would be localized to the week of the election (since it become irrelevant after)